# Assign type level parameter to data structure tree

Tags: haskell, types, type-level-computation

I have a remote microcontroller that exposes some properties in a tree like view. These properties can all be read and some of them can be written to. A property is just a string where each level of the tree is delimited by a `.`.

As an example the property tree looks something like this:

```
Properties.prop1 = 0
Properties.prop2.foo = 1337
Properties.prop2.bar.baz1 = "hello"
Properties.prop2.bar.baz2 = "world"
```

Where `Properties.prop1` and `Properties.prop2.foo` are readable only. `Properties.prop2.bar.baz1` and `Properties.prop2.bar.baz2` are readable and writeable. Anyway I want to encode this in Haskell using strong typing.

```
data Bar = Baz1 String | Baz2 String 
data Prop2 = Foo Int | Bar Bar
data Properties = Prop1 Int | Prop2 Prop2
```

Now you can pretty nicely create a property:

```
p = Prop2 $ Bar $ Baz1 "hello"
```

But what I'm missing is how I can associate a single "path" through these constructors as either a readable property or a read/writeable property. Ideally I would like to have a class or type family "ReadableProp" and "WriteableProp" which would allow me to write something like:

```
writeProp :: WriteableProp a => a -> IO ()
writeProp = ...

readProp :: ReadableProp a => IO a
readProp = ...
```

I know this doesn't work at all right now. But I'm open to change the data structure or use something else to achieve something like this.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: `data RW = Readable | Writable; data Properties (a :: RW) = Prop1 Int | Prop2 Prop2; p = Prop2 @Writable $ Bar $ Baz1 "hello"` ?

Comment: @moonGoose That doesn't encode whether a property is read writeable properly. Now you can instantiate a property to be readable or writeable. But a that's not a choice when instantiating. That's fixed by the protocol.

Comment: GADT then `data Properties where  Prop1 :: Int -> Properties Readable; Prop2 :: Prop2 -> Properties Writeable`

Comment: I’m curious to know what benefit there is to having your values be single paths in the tree and not the tree itself. If you defined your types as products of products instead of sums of sums, you could access any path and you should have the same type safety. Also, you could get away with a typeclass for reading because you know all paths will be readable. I would be tempted to laminate each node in your tree with a Bool (and if you wanted to get fancy, the kind Bool) to indicate whether you can write it, which is similar to the answer you received but with fewer type families.

Comment: @cole I'm not sure I follow. Could post a code snippit to explain this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, instead of representing your property tree path components as a collection of algebraic type "nodes" and constructor "leaves", consider a more uniform representation as a type-level tree that stores the accessibility and type as the tree's (leaf) values:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Kind

data Value = RO Type | RW Type
data Tree = Leaf Symbol Value | Node Symbol [Tree]

type Properties
  = [ Leaf "prop1" (RO Int)
    , Node "prop2" [ Leaf "foo" (RO Int)
                   , Node "bar" [ Leaf "baz1" (RW String)
                                , Leaf "baz2" (RW String)
                                ]
                   ]
    ]
```

If you write a type-level lookup function for property paths:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

type Lookup path = Lookup1 path Properties
type family Lookup1 path props where
  Lookup1 (p:ps) (Node p props' : props) = Lookup1 ps props'
  Lookup1 '[p]   (Leaf p val : qs) = val
  Lookup1 path   (prop : props) = Lookup1 path props
```

that works like so:

```
> :kind! Lookup '["prop1"]
Lookup '["prop1"] :: Value
= 'RO Int
> :kind! Lookup '["prop2", "bar", "baz1"]
Lookup '["prop2", "bar", "baz1"] :: Value
= 'RW String
```

that gives you most of what you need.  With a couple of convenience type-level functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
type TypeOf path = GetType (Lookup path)
type Writeable path = GetAccess (Lookup path) ~ RW
type family GetType (value :: Value) where GetType (access a) = a
type family GetAccess (value :: Value) where GetAccess (access a) = access
```

you can define properties as:

```
data Property path = Property { getProperty :: TypeOf path }
```

letting you create new, type-safe property values like so:

```
> Property @'["prop1"] 5
Property @'["prop1"] 5 :: Property '["prop1"]
> Property @'["prop2","bar","baz1"] "hello"
Property @'["prop2","bar","baz1"] "hello"
  :: Property '["prop2", "bar", "baz1"]
> Property @'["prop2","bar","baz2"] 123  --- type error
```

With a utility class to get a value-level path from a type-level path:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Proxy

class KnownPath (path :: [Symbol]) where
  pathVal :: proxy path -> [String]
instance KnownPath '[] where pathVal _ = []
instance (KnownSymbol p, KnownPath ps) => KnownPath (p:ps) where
  pathVal _ = symbolVal (Proxy @p) : pathVal (Proxy @ps)
```

we can create a fake microcontroller, as a map of path/ioref pairs, where the values in the iorefs are Haskell printable representations that can be marshalled with Read/Show:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import Data.Map.Strict (Map, (!))
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.IORef

type MicroController = Map [String] (IORef String)

newmc :: IO MicroController
newmc
  = Map.fromList <$> mapM (\(k,v) -> (k,) <$> newIORef v) defaults
  where defaults = [ (["prop1"], "0")
                   , (["prop2","foo"], "1337")
                   , (["prop2","bar","baz1"], "\"hello\"")
                   , (["prop2","bar","baz2"], "\"world\"")
                   ]
```

The property read/write functions can be written like so.  Note the use of the `Writeable path` constraint on `writeProp`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

readProp :: forall path. (KnownPath path, Read (TypeOf path))
         => MicroController -> IO (Property path)
readProp mc = do
  let path = pathVal (Proxy @path)
  Property . read <$> readIORef (mc ! path)

writeProp :: forall path. (KnownPath path, Show (TypeOf path), Writeable path)
          => Property path -> MicroController -> IO ()
writeProp prop mc = do
  let path = pathVal prop
  writeIORef (mc ! path) (show (getProperty prop))
```

We can test it like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
deriving instance (Show (TypeOf path)) => (Show (Property path))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  mc <- newmc
  (prop1 :: Property '["prop1"]) <- readProp mc
  print prop1
  -- writeProp prop1 mc  -- type error: couldn't match RO with RW
  (baz1 :: Property '["prop2", "bar", "baz1"]) <- readProp mc
  print baz1
  let baz2' = Property @'["prop2", "bar", "baz2"] "Steve"
  writeProp baz2' mc
  (baz2 :: Property '["prop2", "bar", "baz2"]) <- readProp mc
  print baz2
```

The main advantages of this approach are that the property tree is exposed as as single type-level "structure" with a straightforward tree-like representation, and the `KnownPath` class provides an automatic mapping to value-level property paths, saving you the trouble of writing a lot of boilerplate to map a network of algebraic types to their property paths.  The disadvantages are somewhat uglier syntax, and the need to get the right mix of type applications, proxies, and optional versus mandatory ticked promoters.

Anyway, the full code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Kind
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Map.Strict (Map, (!))
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.IORef

data Value = RO Type | RW Type
data Tree = Leaf Symbol Value | Node Symbol [Tree]

type Properties
  = [ Leaf "prop1" (RO Int)
    , Node "prop2" [ Leaf "foo" (RO Int)
                   , Node "bar" [ Leaf "baz1" (RW String)
                                , Leaf "baz2" (RW String)
                                ]
                   ]
    ]

type Lookup path = Lookup1 path Properties
type family Lookup1 path props where
  Lookup1 (p:ps) (Node p props' : props) = Lookup1 ps props'
  Lookup1 '[p]   (Leaf p val : qs) = val
  Lookup1 path   (prop : props) = Lookup1 path props
type TypeOf path = GetType (Lookup path)
type Writeable path = GetAccess (Lookup path) ~ RW
type family GetType (value :: Value) where GetType (access a) = a
type family GetAccess (value :: Value) where GetAccess (access a) = access

data Property path = Property { getProperty :: TypeOf path }
deriving instance (Show (TypeOf path)) => (Show (Property path))

class KnownPath (path :: [Symbol]) where
  pathVal :: proxy path -> [String]
instance KnownPath '[] where pathVal _ = []
instance (KnownSymbol p, KnownPath ps) => KnownPath (p:ps) where
  pathVal _ = symbolVal (Proxy @p) : pathVal (Proxy @ps)

type MicroController = Map [String] (IORef String)

newmc :: IO MicroController
newmc
  = Map.fromList <$> mapM (\(k,v) -> (k,) <$> newIORef v) defaults
  where defaults = [ (["prop1"], "0")
                   , (["prop2","foo"], "1337")
                   , (["prop2","bar","baz1"], "\"hello\"")
                   , (["prop2","bar","baz2"], "\"world\"")
                   ]

readProp :: forall path. (KnownPath path, Read (TypeOf path))
         => MicroController -> IO (Property path)
readProp mc = do
  let path = pathVal (Proxy @path)
  Property . read <$> readIORef (mc ! path)

writeProp :: forall path. (KnownPath path, Show (TypeOf path), Writeable path)
          => Property path -> MicroController -> IO ()
writeProp prop mc = do
  let path = pathVal prop
  writeIORef (mc ! path) (show (getProperty prop))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  mc <- newmc
  (prop1 :: Property '["prop1"]) <- readProp mc
  print prop1
  -- writeProp prop1 mc  -- type error: couldn't match RO with RW
  (baz1 :: Property '["prop2", "bar", "baz1"]) <- readProp mc
  print baz1
  let baz2' = Property @'["prop2", "bar", "baz2"] "Steve"
  writeProp baz2' mc
  (baz2 :: Property '["prop2", "bar", "baz2"]) <- readProp mc
  print baz2
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, one approach might be something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind (Constraint)
import Data.Type.Bool (If)
import Type.Errors (DelayError, ErrorMessage(ShowType, Text, (:<>:)))

data Bar = Baz1 String | Baz2 String deriving (Read, Show)
data Prop2 = Foo Int | Bar Bar deriving (Read, Show)

data RW = Read_ | Write_
data Props = Prop1_ | Prop2_
data Properties (a :: Props) where
  Prop1 :: Int -> Properties Prop1_
  Prop2 :: Prop2 -> Properties Prop2_
deriving instance Show (Properties a)

type family Permissions (a :: Props) :: [RW] where
  Permissions Prop1_ = '[Read_]
  Permissions Prop2_ = '[Read_, Write_]

type family Contains (x :: k) (xs :: [k]) where
  Contains _ '[] = False
  Contains x (x ': _) = True
  Contains x (_ ': xs) = Contains x xs

type HasPermission (a :: Props) (b :: RW) = 
  If
    (Contains b (Permissions a)) 
    (() :: Constraint)
    (DelayError (ShowType a :<>: Text " does not have required permission " :<>: ShowType b))

class Writeable (a :: Props)
instance (HasPermission a Write_) => Writeable a

class ReadProp (a :: Props) where
  read_ :: String -> Properties a
instance ReadProp Prop1_ where read_ = Prop1 . read
instance ReadProp Prop2_ where read_ = Prop2 . read

class ReadProp a => Readable (a :: Props)
instance (ReadProp a, HasPermission a Read_) => Readable a
```

There's a bit of extra pain setting up the read instances because there's no guarantee of a unique way to construct (eg.) a `Properties Prop1_`, so you have to dictate which constructor to use.

Then we can use it:

```
writeProp :: Writeable x => Properties x -> IO ()
writeProp x = print x

readProp :: Readable x => IO (Properties x)
readProp = read_ <$> readFile "a.txt"

:t readProp @Prop1_
readProp @Prop1_ :: IO (Properties 'Prop1_)
:t readProp @Prop2_
readProp @Prop2_ :: IO (Properties 'Prop2_)

:t writeProp (Prop1 5)
* 'Prop1_ does not have required permission 'Write_
:t writeProp (Prop2 $ Bar $ Baz1 "")
writeProp (Prop2 $ Bar $ Baz1 "") :: IO ()
```

Comment: This does work beautifully! Thank you. But I guess I wasn't clear in my question. This approach only has permission on the first layer of the tree (`Prop1` or `Prop2` are readable or writeable) but permissions are grenular to an entire "path". (`Prop2.bar.baz` is write or readable and other properties on the same level do not necessarily share that same permission.).